# Exibir dados de arquivos csv na view

Tags: django

Quero exibir dados dum arquivo no template django. Não sei como. Se no model ou na view. Aplicação ucsal.

Model:

```
from django.db import models
import pandas as pd

class Arquivo(models.Model):

    def __dados__(self):
        return pd.read_csv("tweets_classificados.csv", encoding='ISO-8859-1', sep=";", header=0)  

view  
from django.http.response import HttpResponse  
from django.shortcuts import render  
from .models import Arquivo  

def index(request):  
    Arquivo.__dados__(self) #esta linha dá erro porque não encontra self.  
    return render(request, 'ucsal/index.html')
```

Não sei se importo pandas no model e passo o uma variável com o valor de

```
pd.read_csv("tweets_classificados.csv", encoding='ISO-8859-1', sep=";", header=0)
```

ou se da forma que estou fazendo é a correta.

o projeto está no github:

https://github.com/andredsn/mineracaodados

Comment: No models ou na view? Se os dados estão estáticos no seu csv, não vejo o porque salvá-los num model. Você pode ler os dados do CSV e montar uma matriz na view. Depois disso, passe a matriz para o template e monte sua tabela. Ou ainda se quiser transformar tudo em JSON na view e montar com Javascript na página.

Comment: @Leonardo Pessoa
 você provavelmente não compreendeu minha dúvida. Eu não consigo ler o arquivo csv. Já criei uma pasta dentro do aplicativo ucsal (ucsal/modulos/arquivo.py) e mesmo assim não consigo. Só encontro exemplo com banco de dados. Me parece que não é tão comum ler arquivos e exibir num browser.

Comment: Entendi. Tentou colocar com o `PROJECT_ROOT` no caminho do arquivo? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067107/read-a-local-file-in-django Senão, não tá gerando nenhum erro quando acessa a view pra abrir o arquivo?